# How do I override Flutter theme to make my app background a specific color?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on the UI for an app, and I'm trying to make the background of each main page the following color:
#131311
hsl(60,6%,7%)
rgb(19,19,17)
The sidebar is showing up in this color, but for some reason the background is an ugly purple color that I'm assuming Flutter's theme maker picked for me.

My code for the theme is as follows:

```
theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(19, 19, 17, 255),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(19, 19, 17, 255),
          fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
         ),
```

Comment: try to change the `scaffoldBackgroundColor` if it makes any better

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Copy the theme with an adjusted color scheme.

```dart
ThemeData themeData = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(19, 19, 17, 255),
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(19, 19, 17, 255),
  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
);
ThemeData newTheme = themeData.copyWith(
  colorScheme: themeData.colorScheme.copyWith(
    background: Colors.red, // Put the color you want
  ),
);
```